# Get all html files in directory through terminal that don't have explicit extension

Tags: html, matlab, shell, terminal, grep

I need to get all the .html files in a folder through the terminal or MATLAB, but the catch is that these .html files don't have an .html extension explicitly in the files. In this case, I'm also trying to catch files that are .GIF's as well but don't have the extension explicitly.

I've written a script that can do this in MATLAB that calls the unix function to basically loop around all the files in the folder, reads them  and gets their extension to lastly remove them from the folder.

My code successfully does it, but it takes too long (maybe about an hour). There are around 12'000 files in the folder, but I'm looking for something more time-efficient despite the size. I'm sure there's a shortcut by two or three lines in the terminal.

```
close all; clear all;

Z=dir('./');
file_number=length(Z)-2;

stats=[];
stats2=[];

for i=1:file_number
    file_name=Z(i+2).name;
    command=['cat ' file_name ' | grep GIF'];
    stats=~unix(command);
    command2=['cat ' file_name ' | grep html'];
    stats2=~unix(command2);

    if stats==1 || stats2==1
        command3=['rm ' file_name];
        unix(command3);
    end

    if rem(i,100)==0
        disp(i);
    end
end
```

Another important detail:
My files don't have .html or .gif in their names. I know they have that type due to their magic numbers (and by right clicking and seeing the files properties). My files names are "1","2" , ... , "7" ,... "11498". They ideally be "1.html" ,"2.gif", "3.jpg", etc .. but they're not.

Comment: Right now you're finding files containing `html` in them as .html files. Is that what you want to do? What about checking MIME type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I got the magic stick:

```
grep -r -l -E "GIF|html" . | xargs rm
```

works like a charm. (Took only 3 minutes for the computer).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could combine the two grep commands in a single one :

```
grep -E "GIF|html" file_name
```

Also, regarding GIF files, I think it might be possible to avoid copying the whole file since the first three bytes are actually needed.

Comment: This might help, do you know how I can convert my matlab code solely to a shell script though? Maybe it's faster that way.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I can't check it on linux, but here's my code (for bash):

```
% HTML part
command=['for f in ./*; do if grep -q "<html>" "$f"; then  printf "$f\n" >> html_files; fi; done'];
stats=~unix(command);
% GIF part
command2=['for f in ./*; do first_bytes=$(head -c 3 $f); if [ "$first_bytes" == "GIF" ]; then printf "$f\n" >> gif_files; fi; done'];
stats2=~unix(command);
```

For the gif files, the first 3 bytes should read "GIF". For the html files, it probably has to contain < html>. Those will create 2 files (gif_files, html_files) containing the desired filenames for GIF and HTML files respectively. All you have to do is `textscan` (or `textread`) those 2 files to get the filenames. I suppose this method will be faster since the control stays on the bash shell instead of ping-ponging to shell and back to MATLAB for 20k+ times!

ATTENTION! Make sure gif_files and html_files don't exist (or at least, that they're blank) or else you might read duplicate data.